# The parking machine implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, state-machine

I am interesting in the topic of **finite automata**, so I started over by implementing a parking machine from this video: [Computers Without Memory - Computerphile](https://youtu.be/vhiiia1_hC4) to understand conceptions. Didn't do much of an error checking - have made a minimal working version.

**Short description of the task, but for better understanding watch the video:**

1. You have the parking machine which is implemented by the finite automaton.
2. The parking lot costs 25 pence. The machine takes only 5, 10, 20 pence coins. Thus, any combination of these coins can be used to pay for parking.
3. After a sum of coins has reached 25 pence, the ticket is issued.
4. The machine gobble up all extra money above the 25 pence, like 20 + 20 pence = the ticket only, no change are given.

**Questions:**

- What do you think about my approach?
- Is it optimal, extendable, suitable for real world applications or this technique has limiting factors and an another should be used?
- How would you implement this machine? It will be good to see another solutions.

It is possible to do this by such way: [Explicit state transition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming#Explicit_state_transition_table), may be I will do this also. My target is to implement something more serious like a **regex** engine in the future, but I should read some books/articles before.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def get_coin(current_sum, *functions):
    print(f"Current sum = {current_sum} pence")
    coin = int(input("Insert coin\n"))
    if coin == 5:
        functions[0]()
    elif coin == 10:
        functions[1]()
    elif coin == 20:
        functions[2]()
    else:
        error(current_sum, functions)

def error(current_sum, functions):
    print("Error: only 5, 10, 20 pence coins are allowed\n")
    get_coin(current_sum, *functions)

def zero_pence():
    get_coin("0", five_pence, ten_pence, twenty_pence)

def five_pence():
    get_coin("5", ten_pence, fifteen_pence, twenty_five_pence)

def ten_pence():
    get_coin("10", fifteen_pence, twenty_pence, give_ticket)

def fifteen_pence():
    get_coin("15", twenty_pence, twenty_five_pence, give_ticket)

def twenty_pence():
    get_coin("20", twenty_five_pence, give_ticket, give_ticket)

def twenty_five_pence():
    input("Current sum = 25 pence, press the 'return' button to pay")
    give_ticket()

def give_ticket():
    print("""\nTake your ticket:

Date: 1 November 2019
Start time: \t20:21
End time: \t22:21\n
""")

def parking_machine():
    prompt = """\n\tThe parking machine.

Information:
1. The machine takes 5, 10, 20 coins.
2. The machine doesn't give a change.
3. The parking costs 25 pence.

Press 's' button to start inserting of coins.

"""
    prompt = '#' * 80 + prompt + '#' * 80 + '\n'

    while True:
        button = input(prompt)
        if button == 's':
            zero_pence()

parking_machine()
```

Comment: Please summarize the task from the video for all those who don't want to watch it.

Comment: @RolandIllig It doesn't need to watch the whole video. From `1:00` to `3:00` minutes will be enough. Do you think the people who don't want watch the 2 minutes of video will be spending time to read my summarization and answering me? I don't think so. But if the rules of this site requires a textual presentation of the task, I will do this. But the video explanation is better anyway.

Comment: @RolandIllig Summarization is added. I have decided that it is better to have all information in the question. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The point is that the video is 9 minutes and I don't know which part of it is the relevant part. Therefore I would need to spend 9 minutes until I know whether this code review is interesting to me. On the other hand, scanning a textual description of the task takes 10 seconds, which is much less.

Comment: Links to external sites can break over time.  Putting all of the information in the question prevents the question from becoming incomplete in the future.

Comment: The question description says “5, 10, and 20 pence coins”, the prompt says 1, 5 & 10 pence coins”, and the error message claims “1, 5, and 20 pence coins”.  Would you like to clarify which of the 3 the program is supposed to be using?

Comment: @AJNeufeld Fixed. Don't know how this happened :)

Comment: @MiniMax, is reviewing still actual?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, why not? It is always interesting to see comments and others solutions. But I have switched from the **finite automata** topic to others at this moment. I were going to improve my knowledge and answer to this question myself in the future, if no one gives an answer especially. Now, I see one big drawback in implementation by function calls -  if it will be a real application with a long sequence of state changing, it will retain a function in the call stack after every state changing and these functions can't be closed before program's exit.

Comment: @MiniMax Not true.  After `give_ticket()` is called, the stack unwinds to the main `while True` loop.  The stack only holds unclosed functions while a balance is held.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Yes, in this case the drawback will not appear, but I wrote: "*if it will be a real application with a long sequence of state changing*". Imagine a regex engine implemented by this way, that processes a long regular expression. The stack will unwind after whole expression will be processed only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Not a finite state machine

The state machine in the posted code has infinite states.
This is caused by the recursive calls of `get_coin` and `error`.
Consider for example these states:

- zero-pence with nothing entered yet
- zero-pence, after zero-pence and an invalid input
- zero-pence, after zero-pence and an invalid input twice
- ...

And so on. You can see these are different states,
because the content of the stack is different.

There are theoretically infinite zero-pence, five-pence, etc, states.
Practically there are finite, because after enough invalid inputs,
the stack will eventually overflow.

There should be precisely one zero-pence, five-pence, etc, states.

This is easy to fix by replacing the `error` function with a loop inside `get_coin`.

#### There are too many states

Even after making the states finite,
there will still be more states than required by the exercise.

Why, again, because of the stack.
For example, there are two ways to reach 10 pence:

- 0 -> 5 -> 5
- 0 -> 10

At this point, the machine should be in the 10 pence state,
but these two states are not the same,
because the stack stores two different histories.

If you want truly identical ten-pence, fifteen-pence, etc, states,
you have to eliminate history, you have to eliminate stack,
you have to eliminate function calls.

This is easy to fix by implementing state transitions in a loop,
instead of through function calls.

#### Don't use varargs if you don't need it

The `get_coin` function takes a variable number of functions as arguments.
But in fact it will only ever use 3,
and in fact it's only ever called with 3.
Therefore, it would be more natural to give those parameters dedicated, descriptive names.

#### Why convert input to `int`?

The `get_coin` function converts input to `int`,
but doesn't actually perform any numeric operations with it.

#### Use a more portable shebang

Not all systems have Python 3 installed in `/usr/bin/python3`.
A more robust, portable shebang would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Answer (score 7):

Given a state machine *p* which has initial state *s* and final state *f*, then it can only accept 0, 5, 10, 20 as inputs. This can be represented graphically as such:

[image]

Therefore, the machine must continue to run until the sum of the coins entered exceeds or equals 25. Therefore, the Python code can be written to be more faithful to the state machine as:

```
states = {
  "s": {0: "s", 5: "q1", 10: "q2", 20: "q4"},
  "q1": {0: "q1", 5: "q2", 10: "q3", 20: "f"},
  "q2": {0: "q2", 5: "q3", 10: "q4", 20: "f"},
  "q3": {0: "q3", 5: "q4", 10: "f", 20: "f"},
  "q4": {0: "q4", 5: "f", 10: "f", 20: "f"},
  "f": {0: "f"}
}

current_state = "s"

prompt = """\tThe parking machine.

Information:
1. The machine takes 5, 10, 20 coins.
2. The machine doesn't give a change.
3. The parking costs 25 pence.
"""
prompt = '#' * 80 + prompt + '#' * 80 + '\n'
print(prompt)

while (current_state != "f"):
  try:
      current_state = states[current_state][int(input("Insert coin: "))]
  except (ValueError, KeyError):
      print("Error: only 5, 10, 20 pence coins are allowed\n")

print("""\nTake your ticket:

Date: 1 November 2019
Start time: \t20:21
End time: \t22:21\n
""")
```

This removes all issues with recursion and stack overflows as there is no history (it is impossible to determine if state *q1* was reached by accepting state 0 or 5, or any combination of those.

Comment: You are missing return to the initial state after giving a ticket, so the next person can buy a ticket.

Comment: Entering `25` will produce an uncaught `KeyError`, crashing the parking ticket machine.

Comment: In the `q1` state, you permit an invalid coin `15` ... both in code and in the state transition diagram ... and deny (crash with a `KeyError`) the valid `20` coin input.

Comment: Thanks for finding those bugs @AJNeufeld. I have added the return state to the diagram, removed the invalid 25 state and it doesn't crash on KeyError. I haven't added the go-to-initial-state in the program as I'm not sure if it should restart the program when the user has finished.

Answer (score 4):

- For the first question: Your implementation is really good.
- For the second question: Yes, I believe this is suitable for real world applications, though it won't work without knowing mechanical engineering.
- For the third question: I've added my implementation at the bottom of the answer!

Here's how we can improve your current code:

Let's analyze the functions `get_coin`, `give_ticket`, and `parking_machine` as all others are just really simple functions.

### `get_coin`

You don't have to use the function `error`! Instead, use:

```
while coin not in [5, 10, 20]:
    print("Error: only 5, 10, 20 pence coins are allowed\n")
    coin = int(input("Insert coin\n"))
```

If you want, you can replace

```
if coin == 5:
    functions[0]()
elif coin == 10:
    functions[1]()
elif coin == 20:
    functions[2]()
```

with

```
functions[int(coin >= 10) + int(coin >= 20)]()
```

Though it impacts the readability of that part. If I were you, I'd use a comment to explain what that part does!

### `give_ticket`

Instead of

```
    print("""\nTake your ticket:

Date: 1 November 2019
Start time: \t20:21
End time: \t22:21\n
""")
```

I'd rather use

```
    print(
    """
        Take your ticket:

        Date: 1 November 2019
        Start time: \t20:21
        End time: \t22:21\n
    """)
```

With the space. I think it looks like a ticket only then!

Anyway, if you don't want the space, just use `textwrap.dedent`

```
def give_ticket():
    print(textwrap.dedent("""
        Take your ticket:

        Date: 1 November 2019
        Start time: \t20:21
        End time: \t22:21\n
    """))
```

This would remove the leading space in every line.

### `parking_machine`

Same as the last one, except you have to print `The parking machine.` separately as it requires `\t` which `textwrap.dedent` would remove. Also, I'd add `seperate = '#' * 80` and use it instead

Also, I'd rather add an option to quit as the only way to quit this program would be to close it.

### General

Always have a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard over your main code which will prevent it from running while imported from another module.

So,

```
parking_machine()
```

**Should** be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parking_machine()
```

---

This is what the final code would look like:

```
import textwrap

def get_coin(current_sum, *functions):
    print(f"Current sum = {current_sum} pence")
    coin = int(input("Insert coin\n"))

    while coin not in [5, 10, 20]:
        print("Error: only 5, 10, 20 pence coins are allowed\n")
        coin = int(input("Insert coin\n"))

    functions[int(coin >= 10) + int(coin >= 20)]()

def zero_pence():
    get_coin("0", five_pence, ten_pence, twenty_pence)

def five_pence():
    get_coin("5", ten_pence, fifteen_pence, twenty_five_pence)

def ten_pence():
    get_coin("10", fifteen_pence, twenty_pence, give_ticket)

def fifteen_pence():
    get_coin("15", twenty_pence, twenty_five_pence, give_ticket)

def twenty_pence():
    get_coin("20", twenty_five_pence, give_ticket, give_ticket)

def twenty_five_pence():
    input("Current sum = 25 pence, press the 'return' button to pay: ")
    give_ticket()

def give_ticket():
    print(textwrap.dedent("""

        Take your ticket:

        Date: 1 November 2019
        Start time:  20:21
        End time:    22:21

    """))

def parking_machine():
    prompt = textwrap.dedent(
    """

        Information:
        1. The machine takes 5, 10, 20 coins.
        2. The machine doesn't give a change.
        3. The parking costs 25 pence.

        Press 's' button to start inserting of coins or 'q' to quit.

    """)

    prompt = '\n\tThe parking machine.' + prompt

    seperate = '#' * 80 + '\n'

    prompt = seperate + prompt + seperate

    while True:
        button = input(prompt)

        if button == 's':
            zero_pence()

        if button == 'q':
            print('Thanks for using this machine!')
            quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parking_machine()
```

I'll make sure to add more ideas when I get them!

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Here's how I'd implement it if I completely based inputs and outputs off of your program.

```
import textwrap

def give_ticket():
    print("""

        Take your ticket:

        Date: 1 November 2019
        Start time:  20:21
        End time:    22:21

    """)

def parking_machine():
    prompt = textwrap.dedent(f"""
    {'#' * 80}

    The parking machine.

        Information:
        1. The machine takes 5, 10, 20 coins.
        2. The machine doesn't give a change.
        3. The parking costs 25 pence.

        Press 's' button to start inserting of coins or 'q' to quit.

    {'#' * 80}
    """)

    while True:
        button = input(prompt)

        if button == 's':
            current_sum = 0

            while current_sum < 25:
                print(f"Current sum = {current_sum} pence")

                while True:
                    coin = int(input("Insert coin\n"))

                    if coin not in [5, 10, 20]:
                        print("Error: only 5, 10, 20 pence coins are allowed\n")
                    else:
                        current_sum += coin
                        break

            if current_sum == 25:
                input("Current sum = 25 pence, press the 'return' button to pay: ")

            give_ticket()

        if button == 'q':
            print('Thanks for using this machine!')
            quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parking_machine()
```